# Upgraded from Azure 2.4 to Azure 3.0 but unable run locally now

Tags: asp.net, c, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage

So recently I upgraded my ASP.NET project up to Azure 3.0 for .NET from Azure 2.4 for .NET.

Now, I am running into the issue of being unable to run my project locally using CloudBuild on my machine. When attempting to debug it, it will open up, then exit silently without throwing an error.

Does anyone have an idea of what might be going on or what I should be changing to run my project locally again?

Thanks!
cmeks

Comment: What do you mean by "Azure 3.0"? By itself, that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Azure SDK 3.0 i meant.

Comment: Let me try again: *Which* SDK? There are many. Please edit your question to be more specific.